# SOAP error on Heart internet

Tags: php, soap, loopback

I have written following code on a server, which hosted on Heart internet UK.

```
// Pull in the NuSOAP code
require_once('./lib/nusoap.php');
// Create the server instance
$debug = 1;
$server = new soap_server;
// Register the method to exposes
$server->register('hello');
// Define the method as a PHP function
function hello($name) {
    return 'sucess ' . $name;
}
// Use the request to (try to) invoke the service
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
exit();
```

After that when I am trying to call this using this

```
 $siteurl   =   get_option('siteurl');
 $siteurl    =   $siteurl.'/wp-content/plugins/soapserverfortest.php';
 @$client     = new nusoap_client($siteurl);
  // Call the SOAP method
 @$result     = $client->call('hello', array('name' => 'cubet'));
 // Display the result
return $result;
```

I am not getting the result.

When we contacted Heart internet, they said,

> The issue may well be that the soap test is trying to use a loop back
>   connection - that is connecting to and from the same server, over port
>   80.
>
> These kind of connections are blocked on our servers, for both
>   security and performance reasons

Can anyone tell how can I solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: @Sergey I didn't get what you mean...

Comment: I find it difficult to understand what you want done with your code. Call the function on the remote Soap-server, or you check how to script works? If you check the script, try to call it from the local machine.

Comment: Its working in several servers, like hostgator etc.. I have tried it in my local machine too. Its working well. Its showing issues only on the Heartinternet UK servers.

Comment: `Its working in several servers, like hostgator etc.` -it is calling 'loop back connections' - it is answer : `These kind of connections are blocked on our servers, for both security and performance reasons` - It's impossible on `Heart internet`

Comment: Or you can use outer proxy for create loop back connection

Answer (score 0):

Sergey is suggesting that you try changing:

```
$siteurl   =   get_option('siteurl');
$siteurl    =   $siteurl.'/wp-content/plugins/soapserverfortest.php';
```

to:

```
 $siteurl   =   get_option('http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/soapserverfortest.php');
```

It may work, but I assume Heart internet is a shared host with multiple clients per IP address -- in which case it may not work. Worth a try. If not I suggest trying a different host (or finding another solution -- do you really need to consume your own web services?)

Comment: Actually we are using this to check whether the server able to handle SOAP request on it. So we have created a script to test SOAP requests are creating correctly. Thats why are using the above code. Is there any consistent way to check whether the SOAP is enabled in server?

Comment: Can't you call the script from a remote computer? If this is your code and you're deploying it everywhere, get it to call via a central proxy.